# Are lord Ganesh ,Lord Subramanya Swamy and Lord Ayyappa are gods or demigods according to bhagavad geeta

Tags: bhagavad-gita, rig-veda

Are lord Ganesh , lord subramanya Swamy and lord Ayyappa are gods are demigods according to bhagavad gita

Comment: Gita does not mention all of them by name. It does mention Skanda (subramanya) as sena pati of devas, so yes he would be a devata (demigod).

Comment: The definition of demi God is **having lesser divine status**.  It is Puranic concept.  In BG, Ganapati and Ayyappa were not mentioned.  Shiva, Vishnu, Skanda were mentioned as the greatest among respective groups.(10th chapter)

Comment: Gita does not address your question.

Comment: If deva means demi god than in b.g. itself, krishna described himself as a deva. I think 3 times. So, i guess, that's it. So, its depends upon the definition of demi god which is a greek term n according to them all avatars, plus children of immortal with mortals like karna, pandava, bhishma, etc are demi gods. Prd.. As in vedas except Rudra every one else are addressed as devas only. So, a deva means god only. The most common example is the word Tridevas. ..

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments from other users, Srimada Bhagvada Gita doesn't deal with the question asked.

Only god Kartikeya (Subramanyam Swamy, Skanda, Murugan, Shanmugha) is mentioned in the Gita in the Chapter on Vibhūti Yoga.

> Srimad Bhagvad Gita [Chapter 10, Verse 24](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=24&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&choose=1)
>
> पुरोधसां च मुख्यं मां विद्धि पार्थ बृहस्पतिम् । सेनानीनामहं स्कन्द:
> सरसामस्मि सागर: ॥ 24 ॥
>
> > 24. O son of Prtha, know me to be Brhaspati, the foremost among the priests of kings. **Among comanders of armies I am Skanda;** among large
> >     expanses of water I am the sea.
>
> English Translation by Swami Gambhirananda

Krishna count Skanda as his one the best of the Vibhūtis (opulences).

Besides that,

There's no explicit mention of the gods - Kartikeya or Ganesha or Ayappa, in the Gita.

So, the answer is Srimada Bhagvada Gita Gita doesn't dwell on the God or demi-god status of any god.

Certainly, since it's spoken by Sri Krishna, several sects consider him to be the Supreme God in the text.

**Besides that, your question cannot be answered from Bhagvad Gita.**